# CGRectOffset animation misbehaved when working with TextField

Tags: ios, xcode

The task is to move the textfield up when user done editing.

Right now, I have a text field `textfield` in the centre of the view, and a method `moveTextFieldToTheTop`.

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [_textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self moveTextFieldToTheTop];
}

- (void)moveTextFieldToTheTop
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     _textField.frame = CGRectOffset(_textField.frame, 0, -100);
                 }];
}
```

Instead of moving 100px up from the centre, `textfield` would somehow appear 100px below the centre and move to the centre position.

<strike>I debugged the code, and find out 
        `[_textField resignFirstResponder];;` is the cause of this problem.</strike>

But I really can't find out why and how to solve this problem.

Can someone please help me?

### Update

I was using `auto layout` when I came across this problem. If I uncheck `use auto layout`, problem solved.

But is there a way to solve this problem with `auto layout` checked?

Comment: In my example project, that I created form your code, text field moved up by 100 point like you want, could you provide some more information ?

Comment: @hsafarya thanks for your reply. I double checked my program after seeing your comment. I was using `auto layout` when came across this problem.

Comment: If you are using auto layout, then you can't change the frame of your view, you need to change constraints, and in animation block call [_textField.superview layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @hsafarya I cant thank you enough. Really appreciate it. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `auto layout` change your `moveTextFieldToTheTop` method with this:

```
     - (void)moveTextFieldToTheTop
{
    //TODO update _textField's constraint to move _textField 100pt up
    [_textField setNeedsLayout];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     [_textField layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
}
```

if you are using storyboard, then connect constraint of _textField to view controller, and update the code TODO part with that constraint(you need to change constraint .const property by 100)

**Update**

Here is the example project with textfield, just run the example, touch on textfield to open keyboard, and then press `return` button on keyboard.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x138ta2uy1z3bbo/ToolBarhighlightproblem.zip?dl=0